# unable to start the jenkins service

Tags: jenkins

I'm very new to jenkins.
I installed the jenkins by this:

```
brew install jenkins-lts
```

whiches was installed in the path of:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.204.1/libexec/jenkins.war
```

then I copied the `jenkins.war` into Download folder and run the command of `java -jar jenkins.war`.

when I open the http://localhost:8080, it always shows me the 503 error like this:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 503 Service Unavailable
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 483
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 13:20:33 GMT
Expires: 0
Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: Idea-9162083a=7af35695-da6a-4307-a39e-b0493b0245ba; JSESSIONID.b339e4d1=node06g9kw8xovnem1325lww2jfx880.node0; JSESSIONID.4f333b19=node0dvxpga8oouhul4beqym36aa90.node0; JSESSIONID.5d0d8859=node017xvlsusr2w881dxdwyfw8bhg00.node0
Host: localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
from: /
```

the log didn't show any errors.

if I try to run the jenkins by brew, it shows me an error:

```
Error: Formula `jenkins` is not installed.
```

the java version is also the latest.

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

where I did wrong? or should I config anything?

Comment: The command to start the jenkins-lts installed by homebrew is 'jenkins-lts', however, java -jar path/to/jenkins.war should also have worked. Copying the jar from the place homebrew installed it to another location isn't the right way to do it, but again, I would still expect Jenkins to start normally. Did you run java -jar jenkins.war from the terminal? If so, there should be a lot of logging in the terminal. Do you see a stacktrace there?

Comment: Try to run jenkins using `brew services start jenkins-lts`

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the jenkins via brew, and closed the vpn, use the command of

`brew services start jenkins-lts`

or

`java -jar /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.204.1/libexec/jenkins.war`

are worked as expect.

thanks for your help.

Comment: My command was failing because I forgot to add the "-lts" at the end of jenkins. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I feel like using docker + kitematic is a better solution than brew for your use case.

right click on the docker icon in the systray, select kitematic, follow the instructions to install it. Login (or skip), search for jenkins and run it. set a volume on folder /var/lib/jenkins in order to persist your data when you'll upgrade the image

Comment: started with docker is ok, but it doesn't work via java -jar jenkins.war, and I also can't use it in tomcat. I really want to know how it works.